I am a US citizen traveling from Venice, Italy to Portland, Oregon on a one-way ticket. Will there be any problems?
I am a USA citizen traveling from Venice Italy to Portland, Oregon on a one-way ticket. Is that a problem?

Why would it be a problem?

Certainly the US isn't going to ask for proof that you will leave the US.

The US loves to cause problems but you can't really predict them. I've gotten SSSS before when traveling on a one-way ticket to the US as a US citizen

From what I understand, you're wondering if there is a problem during the customs and immigration process back in the U.S. The closest thing I can think of is the flight itself being 13 hours and 25 minutes. Am I correct in understanding that you plan to sleep on the flight itself?

Usually there should be no problem, but if you have an agreement with the government which state otherwise (and which we do not know). But if you are a free US citizen, you cannot overstay or work illegally (yeah, you could anyway, but let's not pick all exceptions). It may not be common, but many people do it (I did it).

Is it a direct flight? Stopovers may complicate things.

Is the flight going to stop in Iran or North Korea on its way to the US?

@artemist is SSSS in a foreign airport much of a big deal?  My wife got it once when she was traveling to the US on a diplomatic visa (with me, a US citizen), but the flight was cancelled and she didn't get it for the flight we were rebooked onto, so I don't know precisely what it entails.

Yes, at BER they took everything out of our bags, almost making us miss our flight, then groped us


Is that a problem

Not all, why would it ? As long as you have a valid US passport, you are fine.
